If a user downloads a file from Sharepoint by opening the file in desktop app and saving a copy, would the admin know?
For example, if the user opens a file in Sharepoint (let's say a Word doc) and then clicks to edit in their Desktop Application (in this case, Microsoft Word). The file is now open on their local computer in their client desktop application Word. If they go and save a copy of that file and save to their desktop, they now have a local copy of that file on their desktop, similar to if they had just selected to download the file directly from Sharepoint.
Now my question is, is there some log of that save activity so that an admin or security professional could confirm that the file was saved and exported from the sharepoint environment, or is this action not logged or visible to the admin?

Which SharePoint version are you referring to?

Thanks, I'm referring to the current web version. I'm operating within the M365 environment, which I assume is a current version of Sharepoint as it's not an on-prem tenant, but just the standard cloud.
